# Matrix singluar value hint. Need a hint to get started.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Proof: $\sigma$(M) < $\gamma$ if and only if $\gamma^2I$ - $M^*M$ > 0

[image]

Comment: What does $\sigma(M)$ mean? Is it the largest singular value of $M$?

Comment: Yes the largest one.

Comment: Note that $M^* M$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, so the largest eigenvalue of $M^* M$ is given by $\max_{u: \| u \| = 1} u^{\mathsf{T}} M^* M u$. Does this help?